# Keep text file rows by line number in bash

Tags: bash

Have two files. the first file (called k.txt) looks like this

```
lineTTY
lineRTU
lineERT
.....furtherline like this...
```

The other file (called `w.txt`) contains indices of rows which shall be kept. It looks like:

```
2
9
12
```

The indices in the latter file are sorted. Is there a way to do that in bash quickly as my file is large over 1 million rows?

Every line is the row of a matrix in a text file and only specific rows specified in the other file should be in the matrix.

Comment: Might not be really efficient, but you may try: `sed -n -f <(sed 's/$/p/' w.txt) k.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need here is:

```
cat w.txt | xargs  -i{} sed -n '{}p' k.txt
```

if you must also sort a file, then

```
sort -g w.txt | xargs  -i{} sed -n '{}p' k.txt
```